# Why can't php variables be used as the table name in mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP script I am trying to use variable name as the table name in a MySQL statement, but when I use the variable as the table name it give me a syntax error if no ` are used and says Incorrect Table Name '' when ` are used. The code is attached below

```
function toQuery($tblName){
   $t = "testtitle";
   $art = "testarticle";
   $auth = "testauthor";

       return "INSERT INTO `$tblName` VALUES ('$t', '$art', '$auth', null)";
}

mysql_connect("localhost","testuser","pass123");

mysql_query("Use `test_schema`");

if(mysql_query(toQuery("test_table"))){
    echo "Query: ".toQuery("test_table")." was run.";
}else{
    echo "Query: ".toQuery("test_table")." was not run. ".mysql_error();
}
```

When I use the variable $tblName variable it echos an identical query to if i just put test_table straight in the query returned, but the one with out the variable in query executes properly.

Comment: What's the actual error message? Also, you might want to look at [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Comment: Error message for without \`s around the $tblName variable is:
Incorrect Table Name ''

Answer (score 1):

you don't use mysql_select_db() . try this :

```
function toQuery($tblName){
   $t = "testtitle";
   $art = "testarticle";
   $auth = "testauthor";

       return "INSERT INTO `$tblName` VALUES ('$t', '$art', '$auth', null)";
}

mysql_connect("localhost","testuser","pass123");
mysql_select_db('dbname');
mysql_query("Use `test_schema`");

if(mysql_query(toQuery("test_table"))){
    echo "Query: ".toQuery("test_table")." was run.";
}else{
    echo "Query: ".toQuery("test_table")." was not run. ".mysql_error();
}
```

replace your database name eith `dbname`

Comment: the mysql query "USE \`test_schema\`" does what mysql_select_db does

Answer (score 0):

I think You are choosing the database outside the function. It might be because of the variable accessibility.

Try putting the line `mysql_query("Use`test_schema`");` inside function.

```
function toQuery($tblName){
$t = "testtitle";
$art = "testarticle";
$auth = "testauthor";
mysql_query("Use `test_schema`");
return "INSERT INTO `$tblName` VALUES ('$t', '$art', '$auth', null)";
}
```

Comment: Don't think that's the problem since when i just put the actual table name(not the variable) in the INSERT statement, it works.